# Overlaying properties files

Tags: maven, properties, overlay

Is there a way to merge multiple properties files from different maven projects in the same way that maven does war overlays.

Eg if I have 2 different services that both use a core project, can I create a "strings.properties" in all three and have the build merge the strings.properties so that each service can have their own strings file merged with the core version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some more info, it sounds like you need to set up [Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to merge properties files. This also works really well when you need different property values based on which build profile you may be using.

Check out the Maven page I linked for more info. You can pretty much skip the `Hello, World` example and go right to the part about creating your own variables.